# Access body of a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm storing the `request.body` data so I can restore the original form afterwards.
It seems that you can read `request.body` only once. The second time you get a  `RawPostDataException` Exception.

The problem is when I added a `forms.FileField` to my form. Now it seems like even the first access to `request.body` fails with `RawPostDataException` exception.

It looks like when sending files in the form, Django does something and reads the `request.body` object, practically locking it from reading afterwards. This happens even before the Form object initialization.

Is it a bug? How can I access `request.body` content otherwise?

I'm using latest Django (1.11.1).

Comment: Can you use `request.POST` and `request.FILES` instead? How do you restore the original form?

Comment: I'm saving the original form by saving the `request.body` string into the DB. I'm restoring it by passing `QueryDict(original_posrt_string)` to the `Form()` constructor. I cannot serialize `request.POST` into the DB.

Comment: What do you mean by can't serialize `request.POST` into the DB? Can you post the relevant part of your code? I posted some code as an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly feel that you should look in the direction of working with `request.POST` instead. Here is an example of how it can be serialized and deserialized:

```
In [1]: from django.test import RequestFactory

In [2]: from django.http.request import QueryDict

In [3]: request = RequestFactory().post('/', {'foo': 'bar', 'bazz': 'spam'})

In [4]: request.POST
Out[4]: <QueryDict: {'foo': ['bar'], 'bazz': ['spam']}>

In [5]: request.POST.urlencode()
Out[5]: 'foo=bar&bazz=spam'

In [6]: QueryDict('foo=bar&bazz=spam')
Out[6]: <QueryDict: {'foo': ['bar'], 'bazz': ['spam']}>
```

There is another option if you want to use a dictionary and leave (de)serialization to `json.dumps`/`json.loads`:

```
In [7]: qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)

In [8]: qdict.update({'foo': 'bar', 'bazz': 'spam'})

In [9]: qdict
Out[9]: <QueryDict: {'foo': ['bar'], 'bazz': ['spam']}>
```

Comment: Using `request.POST.urlencode()` instead of `request.body` has fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property in your HTML form? Otherwise it usually causes problems while sending files in your request.

Comment: Yes I have: `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons, Django only allows reading POST body once. Since the body is exposed with a file-like API, you can't easily read the file again. Also, you won't be able to change [upload file handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#modifying-upload-handlers-on-the-fly) if you have already read the data. Failing to read POST data only once will fail, and it is tricky to debug for two reasons.

- Django only reports its error the second time you access the body, so it can be difficult to track the first time it was accessed.
- A myriad of different issues may cause this. One way is to print the full traceback (with traceback.print_stack()) whenever the data gets read (in django/http/request.py: HttpRequest.read and HttpRequest.readline).

So, did you access request.method somewhere in your code? Are you using Django test client? There are many other reasons I don't know.

From the docs,

> HttpRequest.body¶
>
> The raw HTTP request body as a byte string. This is useful for processing data in different ways than conventional HTML forms: binary images, XML payload etc. For processing conventional form data, use HttpRequest.POST.

After searching a lot on this context, I had stumbled upon a [ticket (HTTPRequest::raw_post_data broken for tests)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16822)

In the ticket, there is explicitly said,

> It's an assumed invariant that you won't access raw_post_data having read it once, but the problem is that there are two paths to reading it, one of which (non-multipart) populates the _raw_post_data memo (and hence you *can* access raw_post_data as many times subsequently as you like) and one of which (multipart) doesn't, the latter on the basis that multipart data can be "big" and it'd chew up memory.

But, after all this being said, there is a work around which is not safe at all, fact to be said. By disabling 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' it can be achieved.

Accessing request.POST inside [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) from process_request or process_view will prevent any view running after the middleware from being able to modify the upload handlers for the request, and should normally be avoided.
The [CsrfViewMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware) class can be considered an exception, as it provides the [csrf_exempt()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) and [csrf_protect()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect) decorators which allow views to explicitly control at what point the CSRF validation should occur.

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is to save the form to retrive it later, you can use :

```
form.save(commit=False)
```

no need to save `request.Post` anymore